# SQL to get the common rows from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables T1 and T2.

Can any one please help with a SQL query which will fetch the common rows from these two tables? (Assume T1 and T2 has 100 columns each)

P.S : I guess INNER JOIN on each of the columns will not be a good idea.

Thanks

Comment: two table have any relationship in between?

Comment: What do the tables contain? please post a full data schema

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I use MS-ACCESS 2007 to learn SQL

Answer (score 8):

If you are using SQL Server 2005, then you can use Intersect Key word, which gives you common records.

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT column1
FROM table2
```

If you want in the output both column1 and column2 from table1 which has common columns1 in both tables.

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 IN
(
SELECT column1
FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT column1
FROM table2
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [INTERSECT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php)

```
SELECT * FROM T1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM T2
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, INNER JOIN will work.

eg. SELECT (column_1, column_2, ... column_n) FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON (condition) WHERE (condition)

This query will fetch the common records (intersection of) in both the tables according to ON condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
  t1.*
from
  t1, t2
where
 (
  (t1.col1 is null and t2.col1 is null) or (
  (t1.col1         =   t2.col1        )
 ) and
 (
  (t1.col2 is null and t2.col2 is null) or (
  (t1.col2         =   t2.col2        )
 ) and
 (
  (t1.col3 is null and t2.col3 is null) or (
  (t1.col3         =   t2.col3        )
 ) and
 ....
 (
  (t1.col100 is null and t2.col100 is null) or (
  (t1.col100         =   t2.col100        )
 )
```

Comment: I am not that experienced in SQL. So if we have 100 columns, it is going to be time consuming to write this query. Isn't it ?. Do we have any alternative ?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT NAME FROM Sample1
UNION 
SELECT NAME FROM Sample2;

EX: Table Sample1
ID NAME
-------
1   A
-------
2   B
-------

Table Sample 2
ID NAME
--------
1   C
--------
2   B 
------

Output
NAME
----
A
---
B
---
C
---
```

Comment: How union can help you to give the common rows between two tables. This is wrong. Instead follow below answers to use intersect clause